# Run a function from another form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I've got Module Main() with a function called Main() in Form1

```
Public Module Main 
 Public Sub Main()

 End Sub
End Module
```

And I want to run this from Form2 
doing Form1.Main() won't work because that will look for a class in form2 named form1.

So how can I do this?

Comment: That is a Module, not a form. You'd call `Main.Main()` or just `Main()`. If the Module is nested in Form1 you'd have to call `Form1.Main.Main()`.

Comment: I know this already, but the problem is that typing Main.Main() or Main() the code will refer to Form2, and there is no Main.Main in form2.

Comment: What about my last suggestion? Also, please add more code. We cannot see the whole picture here. Why do you even need a Module in a form??

Comment: Sent you an email with better explanation. What I meant is that it looks for main in form2, while the main i want to call is in form1

Comment: Does seem strange... Are you sure you don't have something in Form2 called `Main`? (oh and I've replied to your mail)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I've found your problem. `Main` seems to be a reserved keyword (or it at least serves some other purpose to Visual Studio), so you cannot use it as a class or module name.

If you rename the module to for example `MainModule`, you are then able to call:

```
MainModule.Main()
```

Comment: @Randomizers : No problem!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the structure of the Form1 and Form2 class to target your routines that you wish to run.

```
public class form1 
public shared sub testsub()
msgbox("hello world")
end sub
end class

public class form2 
public shared sub testsub2()
' this will allow you to call a sub from form1 this also works with variables, functions, ect
form1.testsub()
end sub
end class
```