# How to name the main form of my application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, naming-conventions, convention

I often end up calling the main form of my application `main` or `mainForm`.  That doesn't feel right tho, since main is an important function-name as well. Is there any naming convention that defines, what the primary form of your application should be called? Haven't been able to find that yet.

Comment: That's seems you are worrying for nothing. However to answer your question, No I don't know of any naming convention for the primary form of your application

Comment: I think `Main` should be avoided [**since it can cause problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823674/3740093), however `MainForm` is fine and it's what I always use.

Comment: @Steve That's because I used to work without conventions for 2 years, coding multiple applications. Now I had to do changes on one of my first applications and ended up frustrated about my earlier coding days. Problems you have, when you are the only coder in your company  :-) For future projects I'd like to avoid this kind of problem by using conventions.

Comment: @VisualVincent Alright then. If there are no conventions I will probably stick to MainForm as well.

Comment: I don't know of any conventions either, so you just go ahead. :)